# Calendar Module use in Python

Tags: python

I am new to Python. In Python Calendar module `iterweekdays()` function returns iterator to weekdays. How to print weekdays from iterator returned by `iterweekdays()`. My code is:

```
import calendar

for i in calendar.iterweekdays():  
    print i,
```

Comment: What error did you get from this code?

Comment: what do you want to print?

Comment: Error: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "solution.py", line 3, in <module>
    for i in calendar.iterweekdays():  
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'iterweekdays'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to use `calendar` module:

```
import calendar
for day in list(calendar.day_name)
    print(day)
```